# Why does the driver request the USB device to send the USB descriptors?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, driver, device, device-driver

As far as I understand the USB devices introduce themselves by sending a device descriptor to the host which uses the information embedded in the descriptor to find and load the right driver/drivers. What I don't understand is why the drivers need the configuration, interface, endpoint and string descriptors from the device. I know the descriptors describe the device as a whole e.g. number of configurations, interfaces, endpoints, types, the size of the packets, the purpose of each byte in the packet etc. Why can't the drivers include this information from the start? Why does the USB device hold this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the main reason is *because it was designed that way*. The designers could just as easily have gone the other way as you say.

Possibly more helpfully, I can think of a few reasons *why* they *did* decide on it this way:

- Consider the context in which USB came about. PC peripheral connectivity was a mess. You had serial (UART) ports, PS/2 keyboard & mouse, parallel ports in various modes (e.g. ECP and EPP), game port & MIDI, the various SCSI variants, etc. Most of these did not allow for self-describing devices in a standardised way, demanding custom drivers for each type of device, and mostly manual driver loading. Device descriptors alone would mostly solve the problem of selecting the correct driver, but not necessarily the issue of needing a custom driver for each device.
- Various standard device class specifications (e.g. HID, audio) define their own class-specific descriptors for communicating device variations to the standard driver. For this reason alone the generalised descriptor mechanism is useful.
- [Composite devices](https://www.usb.org/defined-class-codes#anchor_BaseClass00h) in their present form would effectively not be possible without standardised interface descriptors. You'd presumably have to make each composite device act as a hub with multiple devices attached.
- Many (most?) standard device class specifications mandate a certain minimum number of endpoints where the standardised protocol is implemented, (e.g. bulk-only USB mass storage defines 1 bulk input and 1 bulk output endpoint) while devices are free to add more for vendor-specific extensions, or…
- …future expansion of the standard device class or USB standard itself while maintaining backwards compatibility both ways (old driver/new device, new driver/old device). Think of UASP devices that fall back to regular bulk-only mass storage transport.

While not strictly necessary for making all those things happen, making devices self-describing in this way does seem to have been a success overall.